# ¿Cómo guardar datos de Excel en un arreglo c#?

Tags: c#, excel

Estoy trabajando con la extracción de datos desde Excel hacia Visual Studio, la columna que quiero trabajar son datos numéricos, y quiero manejar ciertas operaciones sobre eso...
¿Cómo podría guardar en un arreglo esa columna de la hoja de Excel para empezar a hacer los cálculos?

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto 
[Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede tratar de mejorar 
su pregunta mirando este link [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada, ya que no cumple con los estándares del sitio, no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu comenatrio.

Comment: Puedes Mostrar tu código actual, para poder ayudarte?

Comment: Mira lo que hacen por aqui : [How to read an Excel file using C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-read-excel.htm) Saludos, desde españa